# Bootstrap 5 video carousel controls and videos not showing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I come here because I'm having problems with the coding of a website for a friend's company. he wants to add a video carousel to his website that already had a ccs, so I added the links and scrips for bootstrap to make him a gallery for his protects and a carousel to show videos of his events.

the problem is that the carousel is not showing as I want it and not working as intended, IDK why I have been searching on the internet and troubleshooting the site for a couple of hours and I seem to find no solution. cause of that I come here again to ask for your wisdom.

here is a snippet of the code of the carousel.

```
<!--aqui comienzala seccion de videos -->
    <section id="videos">
        <div class="container-fluid col-8 offset-2">
            <div id="carousel_nuevo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
                    <li data-target="#carousel_nuevo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel_nuevo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel_nuevo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel_nuevo" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <video width="900" height="600" border="5" controls="controls">
                            <source src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/video/forest.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">
                            <h3 class="h3-responsive">video 1</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <video width="900" height="600" controls="controls">
                            <source src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/video/Agua-natural.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">
                            <h3 class="h3-responsive">video 2</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <video width="900" height="600" controls="controls">
                            <source src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/video/forest.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">
                            <h3 class="h3-responsive">video 3</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <video width="900" height="600" controls="controls">
                            <source src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/video/Tropical.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">
                            <h3 class="h3-responsive">video 4</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel_nuevo" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">siguiente</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel_nuevo" role="button" data-slide="next" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">anterior</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

    </section>
    <!--fin seccion videos -->
```

as you can see I'm using the default carousel that you can find as a demo on w3school and other sites.

[image]

As you can see now it's not seems to be loading properly and the other videos are not showing.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: <video style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }} controls autoPlay loop>
                                                <source src={`/video/${testimonial.video}`} type="video/mp4"></source>
                                            </video>

or if you would like to use npm package then use to npm i react-player 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player

Answer (score 0):

```
<video style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }} controls autoPlay loop> 
<source src="file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</source>
 </video>
```

or if you would like to use npm package then use to `npm i react-player npmjs.com/package/react-player`